# delete shared preference data when i install same application means overriding application

Tags: android

i use shared preference for saving data but when i install same application then my shared preference data not delete it remains as it is so how to delete shared preference data when i install same application without uninstall the application means just over write on the same application.

```
          SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor  editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("MY_NAME", UserId);
         editor.putString("PASSWORD", password);
        editor.commit();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried below code to make this work change it to suit your needs

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
if (!isFirstRun)
{
    // Code on first run 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
else
{
     // DO something
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
     editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
     editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: what would be on "else" means if i install application first time then it should be save data on preference means then editor.clear() would not be called?am i right?

Comment: yeah correct only if the app is run second time then clear will be called otherwise "else" part will be called so save your stuff in "else" part

Comment: hey ingsaurabh i install same application second time then also  if (!isFirstRun) block is executing..it should be false when i install second time same application

Comment: the term is installing the application ,not running same application again and again

Comment: Actually I just gave you the idea I mentioned change it to suit ur needs BTW I have updated the answer check that

Comment: I understood u clearly ur requirement can be fulfilled by above mentioned code

Comment: in else{} part of ur code u put "false"  in preference.when it would be true for executing  else part again?i dont want to clear preference value on each run of application but only on new installation.so if i open application (not install) again then it will go to else {} part means again it would clear data from pref.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721188/how-to-delete-the-shared-preference-file-from-android-application-when-re-install